# What is the best way for Lists in partial view in an ASP.NET Core form?

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this class that I want to use as model for a complex `<form/>` in ASP.NET Core, below is the sample form

```cs
// Model
public class Member
{
    [BsonId] 
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }

    public List<MemberChild>? Children { get; set; } = new();
}

// MemberChild class
public class MemberChild
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Birthdate { get; set; }
}

// Main form view for Member object
@model Member
<form method="post"
      autocomplete="off" action="/register">
        <div class="mb-2 ms-2">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="Name></span>
        </div>
        <button>Add Child</button>

...and so on
```

Now, this `MemberChild` model has its own partial view, it looks like this:

```cs
// MemberChildForm.cshtml partial view
@model MemberChild

<div>
        <input placeholder="0"
               type="hidden"
               asp-for="Name"
               class="d-inline">
        <input placeholder="0"
               type="hidden"
               asp-for="Birthdate"
               class="d-inline">
</div>
```

It can be fetched from this controller action

```
[HttpGet("/children-form")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssistanceDataForm()
{
    return PartialView("MemberChildForm", assistance);
}
```

I want it so that whenever the user clicked an ' + Add Child ' button a new `MemberChildForm` adds to the form

I've already tried using ajax to get an html partial view of "/children-form" partial view but the problem is the `<input/>`'s `asp-for` or `name` doesn't conform with the parent `<form/>`, it's supposed to be `Member.Children[].Name` but it only shows Name, is there a built in ASP Core solution for this?

To make things easier I want to implement something like this https://cms.jotform.com/uploads/answers/answer/perkplanning/2110000_Screen%20Shot%202020-01-10%20at%209.30.38%20AM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use `asp-for` in your partial view, I suggest you to use `Name` property directly, Because you can add index in it by your self, Here is a simple demo based on your project, Hope you can help you solve your issue.

**Partial View**

```
@model int 
<div>
    <input placeholder="xxx"
           name="Children[@Model].name"
           class="d-inline">
    <input placeholder="0"
            type="date"
           name="Children[@Model].Birthdate"
           class="d-inline">
</div>
```

**action**

```
[HttpGet("/children-form")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AssistanceDataForm(int index)
{
     return PartialView("MemberChild", index);
}
```

**View**

```
@model Member
<form method="post"
      autocomplete="off" action="/register">
        <div class="mb-2 ms-2">
            <label asp-for="Name"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name">
            <span asp-validation-for="Name"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="mb-2 ms-2">
            <label asp-for="Birthdate"></label>
            <input asp-for="Birthdate">
            <span asp-validation-for="Birthdate"></span>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" value="0" id="index"/>
        <div id="child">

        </div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add Child</button>
        <button>Create</button>
</form>

<script>
    var index = document.getElementById("index").value

    document.getElementById("add").addEventListener('click',e=>{
        $.ajax({
            type: "Get",
            url: "/children-form?index="+index,
            success: function(data){
                document.getElementById("child").insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", data)
                index++; // Increment the index value
                document.getElementById("index").value = index; // Update the hidden field value
            }
        })
    })
</script>
```

**Gif Demo**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Epic Gamer, Have you solved this issue now?

Comment: hello, yes I did, I decided to manually write the <input>'s name via js, seems like we can't do this with blazor yet